# asynchronous execution javascript dojo (return a variable result of a query)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I would like to know if it's possible to return a variable in a function after finding the result in a queryTask.

Apparently this is an asynchronous execution but, to be honest, I really need to execute that ..

Here is my simple example I hope you find a solution to remedy it.

```
  myfunction: function (num) {

    var rft = 0;
    var gedlayer = new FeatureLayer("http:mylink/MapServer/1", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields: ["*"]
    });

    var qr = new QueryTask();
    qr.where = "rft=" + num;
    qr.outFields = ["*"];


    gedlayer.queryFeatures(qr, function (featureSet) {
    if (featureSet.features.length > 0) {
    var content = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.features.length; i++)
            {
            rft = rft + featureSet.features[i].attributes.rft;
                    }
    }
    },


    function (error) {
        console.log("Error dans la requette de poste source : " + error);
    }
    );



 return rft;
    }    ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use promises to wait for the results, and do whatever you want with them. You can check the related dojo [Deferred documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html) for better understanding:

```
require([
 ...
 "dojo/Deferred", 
 ...
 ], function (
    ... 
    Deferred
    ...) {

  myfunction: function (num) {
  var rft = 0;
  var gedlayer = new FeatureLayer("http:mylink/MapServer/1", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
  });

  var qr = new QueryTask();
  qr.where = "rft=" + num;
  qr.outFields = ["*"];

  gedlayer.queryFeatures(qr).then(
    handleQueryResults.then(useResultFromQuery), 
    handleError);
},
handleQueryResults: function(results) {
  var deferred = new Deferred();
  var rft = 0;
  if (featureSet.features.length > 0) {
    var content = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.features.length; i++) {
      rft = rft + featureSet.features[i].attributes.rft;
    }
  }
  deferred.resolve(rft);
},
handleError: function(error) {
  console.log("Error dans la requette de poste source : " + error);
},
useResultFromQuery: function (rtf){
  //do whatever you want with rft
}
}
```

Comment: my question was how to return the result in the first function, in your answer it's about the function myfuction (), when I call this function, it does not return the result, the type of the return is undefined !